# Python. Как зациклить конструкцию if elif?

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста, после запуска кода первый if начинает бесконечно спамить, а мне нужно чтобы после if зациклился elif (за ранее простите если я что-то не так объяснил)

Вот часть кода:

```
while True:
    if selectmenu == 1:
        print("Menu one!")
    elif selectmenu == 2:
        loginM = str(input("Login: "))

        if loginM == login:
            passwordM = input("Password: ")
            if passwordM == password:
                print("You login!")
            else:
                print("ERORR")
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Ну так вы selectmenu нигде не меняете и судя по всему оно равно 1, вот на if и клинит

Comment: А как мне это исправить? Мне нужно чтобы после if начал работать elif

Comment: логика не верна. У вас должно работать либо `if`, либо `elif` в одной итерации. Посмотрите на ответ, мне кажется я понял чего вы добиваетесь. После того как сработает первый `if` вы в нем определите новое значение для `selectmenu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```py
while True:
    selectmenu = int(input())
    if selectmenu == 1:
        print("Menu one!")
        selectmenu = 2
    elif selectmenu == 2:
    ....
    else:
        print("Такой опции нет")
```

Где-то надо выбирать значение для `selectmenu`.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, помогло

Comment: На здоровье, не забывайте оценивать и принимать ответы